# Using dcast to widen a data frame

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have the following data frame:

```
z <- data.frame(
                item=letters[rep(24:26,2)],
                freq=c(4,3,2,4,4,1),
                id=rep(1:2,each=3)
               )

item freq id
x    4    1
y    3    1
z    2    1
x    4    2
y    4    2
z    1    2
```

The data frame is unique on every `id,item` combination.

I would it to be like this:

```
id x y z
 1 4 3 2
 2 4 4 1
```

This looks like a fairly simple transform but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is what I have tried (`z` is the name of the data frame):

```
dcast(z,id ~ item,sum)
```

and it returns this:

```
id x y z
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're putting a "sum" function in there. Try this instead:

```
> dcast(z, id ~ item, value.var="freq")
  id x y z
1  1 4 3 2
2  2 4 4 1
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I just figured it out, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: this answer is now wrong, as it produces: "Warning message:
In dcast(z, id ~ item, value.var = "freq") :
  The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a data.frame and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(z). In the next version, this warning will become an error. "

Comment: @tchevrier, don't see how the answer is wrong. (1) The question is about using `dcast` from "reshape2". (2) The question is about using a `data.frame` as the input.

Comment: Please, kindly run your code as written above and see for yourself the warning message stated above. The warning message I copied in full clearly states: "In the next version, this warning will become an error.". Maybe I am wrong, but it seems you need to explicitly call "reshape2::dcast", as you seem to suggest? Sorry if I am in the wrong, but that's what i see on my R console.

Comment: @tchevrier, `dcast` appears in both "data.table" and "reshape2". "reshape2" is not being further developed, but it is being updated enough to stay on CRAN. If "data.table" is loaded *after* "reshape2", its `dcast` masks the one from "reshape2", and this warning is produced. If "data.table" is never loaded to begin with, this answer works just fine. If "data.table" is loaded before "reshape2", this answer works just fine. If both "data.table" and "reshape2" are loaded, then the user is better off specifying which namespace they want to use by using `package::function`. The answer's still OK.

Comment: totally agreed - but nowhere did this show in the above answers. than you for the clarifications.

Comment: @tchevrier, The reason there's no explicit mention of this is because at the time of the question and answer (July 2013) there wasn't a "data.table" version of `dcast`. `dcast.data.table` wasn't introduced until Feb 2014, and wasn't a `data.table` generic until Sep 2015. So, at the time, there was only one `dcast`, which came from "reshape2", which was mentioned in the tags. There's interesting reading about the process in the NEWS files at the data.table Github pages in case you're interested.